# rails giving activerecord instead of id

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to click on link to show what is in products page
[image: I want to click on link to show what is in products page]

when id do `/products/1` it shows my product < this is correct
but when i click on the link it shows `products/%23<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f11426994c0>`
and this is different for every link i click on.  Now the problem is when i click on the link it says `Couldn't find Product with 'id'=#<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f11426994c0>` it should it no do the id instead of ActiveRecord ???

this is my **Product Controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  include ProductsHelper

  # before_action :logged_in?, only: [:index, :show, :edit]
  before_action :admin_only, only: %i[destroy reset_votes]

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end
  
  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end 

  def create
    @product_params = params.require(:product).permit(%i[name size image])
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def add_to_cart
    id = params[:id].to_i

    if session[:cart].include?(id)
      session[:cart].delete(id)

    else
      session[:cart] << id
    end

    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
  end

  def show
    @products = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    product_params = params.require(%i[name size image])
    @product.update_attributes(product_params)
  end
  

  private

  def product_params
    params.require(:category).permit(%i[name size image])
  end
end
```

this is my **Product Index** as shown in picture one

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Image</th>
  </tr>
  <% Product.all.each do |f| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to f.name, product_path(@products) %></td>
    <td><%= f.size %></td>
    <td><%= f.price %></td>
    <td><%= image_tag(f.image, :width => "60%") %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Another problem i have is when i visit `products/1/edit`
and fill in the form it gives another problem saying that `No route matches [PUT] "/products/1/edit"` in my routes i have given it as `resources :products`

this is the **products/edit.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit Product - ") %>
<h1>Edit Product <%= @products %></h1>
<p class="lead">Fill out the following fields</p>
<%= render 'products/form', products: @products, url: products_path(@products), method: :put %>
```

this is the **products/_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="form">
  <%= form_for :products, method: method do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/flash_messages' %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Product Name' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :size %>
      <%= f.text_field :size, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Product Size' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :price %>
      <%= f.text_field :price, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Product Size' %>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :image %>
      <%= f.file_field :image, hidden: true %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary btn-primary--wide', value: 'Update Product' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you mixed up between `singular` and `plural` form of a variable!

in your **product** > **index** file, change the following line:

`<td><%= link_to f.name, product_path(@products) %></td>`

To:

`<td><%= link_to f.name, product_path(f) %></td>`

Why this change? You're running a loop with `@products` and you're sending inside the `product_path` this `@products` variable which is a AR record list! You should send only one product object which is `f` as you defined in the loop. [It's a very bad naming of variable]

Another thing:

Same issue in the `update` form:

`<%= render 'products/form', products: @products, url: products_path(@products), method: :put %>`

Here you should pass `@product`, not `@products`!
You're updating a single record, not a list of products, right?

Comment: that makes alot of sense!

but the problem now is that when i click on the update product it shows `No route matches [PUT] "/products/1/edit"`

Comment: in your `products/_form` file use this: 
`<%= form_for @product do |f| %>` line. and remove `<%= form_for :products, method: method do |f| %>` this line. 
Then see the magic! @AndrewTran

Answer (score 0):

As you are looping on Products array and the local variable you are using `f` then you have to use `f` instead of `@products`. like, `<td><%= link_to f.name, product_path(f) %></td>`.
Also, for edit template I think you can use below changes.

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit Product - ") %>
<h1>Edit Product <%= @product %></h1>
<p class="lead">Fill out the following fields</p>
<%= render 'products/form', products: @product, url: products_path(@product), method: :put %>
```

Another thing you can try `rails scaffold` command which generate all codes for you from where you can get some idea.